# Writing a script that runs constantly while editing

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way to write python scripts that run at a given framerate while editing? For example, automatically move objects or do more interesting actions based on scene state or external events while editing (not while animation playing).

Comment: Are you trying to make a game? This sounds really niche and difficult not only to create but to utilize as well. Please clarify what you’re wanting to achieve, as I feel you may be trying to build an elevator in order to get the newspaper off the roof: There’s probably a ladder.

Comment: No, not game. Just sometimes I need simple scripts, that for example keep symmetry between object. My last question here was how can I achieve metaballs to remain symmetical. Mirror modifier is not working for metaballs, and I don'r know any other trick to do this, but I can write a little script that can transform coordinates / copy properties of the edited metaball primitives.

An other example is to use external devices (MIDI, VR, camera) to help editing.

Comment: Oh, that sounds much more practical than I thought. I thought you wanted to edit the script and have it continuously run or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Application Timers (bpy.app.timers)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html#module-bpy.app.timers) to run scripts continuously repeating at some time interval.

You can also use [Application Handlers (bpy.app.handlers)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=handler#module-bpy.app.handlers) that are triggered when something happens like something is changed in your scene ([bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=handler#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post))

See the documentation for examples how they are used. It's quite clear and simple, but don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear.