# How to trigger a script after completing object transform?

Tags: python, scripting

If I move an object or rotate an object and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm, I would like to trigger a function. Is this possible?

I did research on [app handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) and [msgbus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) to no avail. Is msgbus deprecated in Blender 3.4? Because the documentation's sample code is not working for me.

I would like this. For example, pseudocode I'm trying to make:

```
def on_transform_complete(event):
    print("transform complete/confirmed")

my_object.addEventListener("TRANSFORM_COMPLETE", on_transform_complete)
```

Here's [a similar post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66222/use-an-object-change-to-trigger-python-script) using `scene_update_post`, but it's outdated now and does not work anymore.

I did experiment on `bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post`, but the problem is that it keeps updating while dragging object, but I need my update to trigger only exactly once after the drag is confirmed with a final position or rotation or scale. There must be some "complete" event that gets dispatched which I can listen or subscribe to.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274172/111042

Comment: yeah unfortunately their documentation is lacking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I noticed [bpy.context.active_operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.active_operator) returns a pointer to a different location on the last callback to `depsgraph_update_post` when moving an object with the mouse. It means the test for equality between the two will likely yield `False`. I don't know how or why but we can leverage that "feature".

[image]

I'll piggyback on james_t's answer on this same Q&A.

```
import bpy
    
def transformEvent(obj, scene):
    print('transformEvent')

def on_depsgraph_update(scene):
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    if on_depsgraph_update.operator is None:
        on_depsgraph_update.operator = bpy.context.active_operator
    for update in depsgraph.updates:
        if not update.is_updated_transform:
            continue
        if on_depsgraph_update.operator == bpy.context.active_operator:
            continue
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        transformEvent(obj, scene)
        on_depsgraph_update.operator = None

on_depsgraph_update.operator = None

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(on_depsgraph_update)
```

Comment: Hey! i took a look at the pointer as well and didn't notice they were different! i should've paid closer attention haha awesome!

Comment: wow this hack is the correct solution since there is no other solution thank you sooo much! XD

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie hehe glad it helped :)

Comment: Something like this should be added to the scripting Templates. I suggest this in rightclickselect https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/KQ6G -- perhaps vote or comment on this?

Comment: @james_t agreed ! although it's a bit hacky so I think the devs will say they prefer waiting for an officially designed and supported feature, which may or may not come in our lifetime ><

Comment: @james_t thank you, i've upvoted and my friend as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script that will trigger when I move an object in the 3d View

```
import bpy
    
def transformEvent(obj, scene):
    print('transformEvent')

def on_depsgraph_update(scene):
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    for update in depsgraph.updates:
        if update.is_updated_transform:
            obj= bpy.context.active_object
            transformEvent(obj, scene)

# Make blender call on_depsgraph_update after each
# update of Blender's internal dependency graph
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(on_depsgraph_update)
```

Comment: Hey cool thanks for the new answer. I'll have to check it tomorrow. Does it only trigger once?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie -- no it still *suffers* from being "invoked too often".  Might have to set a timer event to then do whatever... ugh!  perhaps there's some way to see if LMB is up.

Comment: oh no :( but it looks like the solution is very close!

Comment: you can get the current operator with `bpy.context.active_operator`. It's possible the last callback happens when the operator is finished so it will return None otherwise it will point to the transform operator. wild guess :)

Comment: @Gorgious thanks! i think it is impossible since it probably was never implemented by the developers because I've been searching for the answer for several months now. Well at least nobody knows how to do this. I feel that the last resort is to write a bug report in order to reach out to the developers since there is no other way to get this type of information? What do you think? I think that "operation complete" handlers are pretty basic functionality that should have been shipped with the blender python API.

Comment: I think I found something. Looks hacky though. I'll post an answer

Comment: by the way +1 to both of you for getting me to a "solution" hahaha