# How to know if the active node in a node tree change?

Tags: python, scripting

I need to know if the active node of a node changes.
I have found this example for the active object, that works very well:

```
import bpy
        
def msgbus_callback(*arg):
    # in console will be print selected_objects 
    print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
    # you can do something
        
def subscribe_to_obj(): 
             
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.LayerObjects, 'active'),
        owner=bpy,
        args=('something, if you need',),
        notify=msgbus_callback
        )
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subscribe_to_obj()
```

I try to do something like that for the active node in node tree, but it doesn't work:

```
import bpy
        
def msgbus_callback(*arg):
    # in console will be print selected_objects 
    print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
    # you can do something
        
def subscribe_to_active_node(): 
             
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.Nodes, 'active'),
        owner=bpy,
        args=('something, if you need',),
        notify=msgbus_callback
        )
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subscribe_to_active_node()
```

A way could be **observing** if the operator `bpy.ops.node.select()` is called, but I don't know how.

Comment: You might want to try the ``bpy.app.handlers``` as described by this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283286/111042).  I'll see if I can figure out your specifics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. The problem is that selecting a node in a nodetree doesn't update the depsgraph ...

Comment: A way could be observing if the operator "bpy.ops.node.select()" is called, but I don't know how

Comment: Polling. Simply check on a short interval if currently active (selected? That's a different thing) has changed since the last check.